# Redis select with many condition

Tags: redis, conditional-statements

I have 3 hashes

hmset download_product|1 id 1 product_id 1 time 123456

hmset download_product|2 id 2 product_id 3 time 123458

hmset download_product|3 id 3 product_id 1 time 123459

I want to select

select all value where product_id = 1 and time between(123451, 123460).

Help me, (sorry about my bad english)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: What is the "value" that you are trying to "select" ? Is it the number after the | in the hash names?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using ZADD and ZRANGEBYSCORE for your kind of requirement. For details check out the documentation at  http://redis.io/commands

Comment: thanks for your help
but if i want to select

"select all value where status = 1 and category = 2 and type = 3 and create_time between (123451, 123460)"

what i should to do ?